# PHP cURL get last redirect URL from t.co

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, curl

I got this function to detect a page's redirect final URL

So, if I call the function with google.com it will detect the redirect and bring back http://www.google.co.ve or http://www.google.co.ar, http://www.google.co.il, etc...

This tells me that this is detecting the final URL properly... now when I try with a shortener service like t.co and I use this link as an example... t.co/0BWUquGyj3 it will return t.co/0BWUquGyj3 again, instead of detecting the return URL

```
function parse_url($url, $user_agent = 'desktop') {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILETIME, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 45);    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 45);    
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 120);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0");
    $curl_exec = curl_exec($curl);
    $header = curl_getinfo($curl);
    $final_url = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($curl);

    return $final_url;
}
#http://t.co/0BWUquGyj3
$cosas = parse_html("t.co/0BWUquGyj3");
echo $cosas; //returns t.co/0BWUquGyj3 instead of the final redirect URL
```

Comment: my solution worked? If yes mark like correct the answer please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function unshorten_url($url) {
  $ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // the magic sauce
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE, // suppress certain SSL errors
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, 
  ));
  curl_exec($ch); 
  return curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
}
```

Output:

```
echo unshorten_url("t.co/0BWUquGyj3"); // https://twitter.com/zaynmalik/status/626878040472223744/photo/1
```